# Install rails assets in a ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am transforming a ruby plugin to a ruby gem. In the plugin I was able to run

```
rake gem_name:install
```

This would install javascript and images into the rails assets directory. Can I automate this, so when i include the gem in mijn gemfile, this is all included automatically?

What is the way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need install your styles and scripts into the rails app in rails 3.1 and 3.2.

Just put them into `app/assets`, `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets`; and add `Rails::Engine` class to you gem (it can be empty).

[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems)